# How to properly set permission for github webhook

Tags: git, file-permissions, webhooks

I have set up github webhook so that my server auto pull from specified branch from my repo. To make it work I made www-data the owner of all the repo files on the server (else it won't be able to write those files).

But now I read that it's very bad to let www-data be the owner of the files. Is it the case? If yes how can I setup this properly?

Thanks for helping!